# Building tensorflow for windows

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to build tensorflow for my windows machine. I tried building it in ubuntu 16.04 with python3.5 but python on windows doesn't support it. So can someone guide me.

I used material available here [Tensorflow from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources)

Comment: These days I'm running linux mint, switched off of windows a short while back, in no small part because I hated dealing with these issues. Under windows I always just went with using a virtualbox VM and running tensorflow under that environment. Not an answer to your question, but maybe food for thought. A lot more testing / documentation / etc goes into the TF/Linux environment.

Comment: I know this but I have a project wherein I need to run TF on windows

Comment: There are instructions for building TensorFlow on Windows [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.12/tensorflow/contrib/cmake). Can you try those and let us know if you run into problems?